# Systematically removing every Nth entry from a list

Tags: list

I'm trying to remove every *n*th number from a list in a `for` loop, but something's gone wrong

There's a variable that determines what numbers to remove
If I had a list of 1 to 10, and I tried removing every second number, and then third

I should get 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 after removing every second number,
and 1, 3, 7, 9 after removing every third (only one number)

```
for i in range(repeatAmount):
    multiple = int(input())
    del numberVar[1::multiple]
    print(numberVar)
```

This code returns [1, 3, 5, 7, 9] after removing every second number, which is correct

But then returns [1, 5, 7] after removing every third number

I have no idea what's going wrong

Comment: Removing index `1` and every third element after that from a 5-element list will remove indices `1` and `4`. Your result is exactly what it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line

```
del numberVar[1::multiple]
```

to this line:

```
del numberVar[multiple-1::multiple]
```

**Output:** [1, 3, 7, 9]

In your loop, you referenced index #1 both times as your starting index, hence you removed the first and fourth elements (3 and 9) in the second iteration of the loop.

Comment: @PranavTripathi Great! Please accept as the correct answer.